# What is the N designation I see on some screws?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

On some screws, I see a N designation, like "N8". I believe these are sheet metal screws. Here is an example of an N8 screw: https://store.delorean.com/sp10459-sems-screw-n8.html

I have tried to figure out what this means without any success. I would love to know what it means.

Comment: Any more examples?  Likely N is for #, but without a few more at different numbers and possibly with dimensions it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 0):

N8 appears to be a grade of material or manufacture for the given fastener. See [this doc](https://practicalmaintenance.net/wp-content/uploads/Product-Dimensions-and-Tolerances-Standards-for-Threaded-Fasteners.pdf) for some details (Ctrl + F for N8 and you will find details).

Hopefully the information in this document means a bit more to you than it does to me!